# Solve include layout conflict

Tags: android, xml

So I have 3 layouts as follows:

first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/reward_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gift"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outlet_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reward_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="outlet"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="0.0km"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reward"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reward_icon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
        android:layout_below="@id/outlet_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="Reward"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locality"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reward_icon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
        android:layout_below="@id/reward"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="Locality"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fav_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outlet_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="outlet"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="0.0km"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reward"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
        android:layout_below="@id/outlet_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="Reward"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locality"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
        android:layout_below="@id/reward"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="Locality"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

third.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/fav_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/heart"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outlet_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fav_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="outlet"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="0.0km"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reward"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fav_icon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
        android:layout_below="@id/outlet_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="Reward"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locality"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fav_icon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
        android:layout_below="@id/reward"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "15dip"
        android:hint="Locality"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now I made a layout all.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/first" />

    <include layout="@layout/second" />

    <include layout="@layout/third" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is when I use all.xml, image_view is showing reward_icon for all the data whether it should show reward_icon for first set of data, logo for second type of data and fav_icon for third type of data. I am using adaptor as follows:

```
 String[] values = {"outlet_name","reward","locality","distance"};
                    int[] ids = {R.id.outlet_name,R.id.reward,R.id.locality,R.id.distance};
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, 
                                R.layout.all, values,ids);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                      ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: May I know what is `R.all`?

Comment: Reference to all.xml layout.

Comment: Add this android:orientation="vertical" to all.xml Linear Layout and set android:layout_height="wrap_content" to first,second and third xml relative layout.

Comment: @Haresh Hey, I had some problem with emulator so it took some time. Sorry, it doesn't work. Now for every data all the layouts are shown once.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
1.Add this properties android:orientation="vertical" to your LinearLayout in all.xml
2.Change this properties android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" RelativeLayout in first.xml,second.xml and third.xml.
```

Comment: No, it's not. Now it is just showing layouts for 3 time. Once with data and twice without.

Comment: can you please post oslist value ?